# spring data rest hal browser: how to expose resource descriptions and document

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have looked all over the net, trolled through spring-data-rest source code and tried to decipher how the JS for the hal-browser is trying to retrieve 'title' and 'doc' details for a resource. I have also discovered that there are

```
@RepositoryRestResource(
        collectionResourceRel = "roles",
        path = "roles",
        itemResourceDescription = @Description("This is a test description")
)
```

Annotations I can put in the @Repostitory, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Specifically, if you look at [this example,](http://api.opensupporter.org/hb2/browser.html#/api/v1) how do I get "title|doc" to fill in"

I filed a ticket with spring and haven't heard back.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the HAL Browser expects the link to contain the title property. In the example you linked:

```
{
  "motd": "Welcome to the OSDI Example Action Platform OSDI API endpoint!!",
  "_links": {
    "osdi:people": {
      "href": "http://api.opensupporter.org/api/v1/people",
      "title": "The collection of people in the system"
    }
  ...
}
```

The `org.springframework.hateoas.Link` class does not support that property as of version `0.19.0.RELEASE`. No idea about the docs though...